# Минор матрицы с помощью статически-созданных массивов

Tags: c++, алгоритм, 2d

Может у кого есть рабочий код/алгоритм, как вычислить, или хотя бы отделить минор матрицы(просто вычеркнуть лишние строки и столбцы)
!максимальное внимание!Запрещено использовать указатели, динамические массивы, операторы new, delete, любые стандартные шаблоны stl, итераторы, контейнеры, библиотеки для обработки матриц.
Если более кратко, только двумерные и не только массивы и ничего больше.

Comment: Приведите пример исходных данных и требуемого результата.

Comment: Не используйте ненужные столбцы и строки в вычислениях, вот и весь сказ.

Comment: "Запрещено использовать указатели, динамические массивы, операторы new, delete" Это звучит как не используйте языки Си, Си++ и здравый смысл. Где таке курсы все еще встречаются, можно поинтересоваться? Если ничего это не использовать, рамер матицы  известен заранее на момент компиляции, минор получается копированием в такую же с исключением столбцов, или какое-то кодирование исключаемых строк и столбцов.

Comment: Лабораторная в вузе :) Размер известен до компиляции(если сказать точнее, юзается костыль в виде массива 100х100, где используются только размер заданный пользователем) Можно детальнее, как копировать только часть матрицы?

Comment: Эм, в цикле, поэлементно, в теле цикла проверяеся равны ли индексы заданным? Никак иначе. Что такой вопрос возникает , тоже как бы характеризует качество курса. Напоминает непрофильные курсы  и з 80х лет.. "вот есть язык, вот есть оператор такой-то, используйте его".

Comment: да в том и проблема, что я не могу себе представитть как в цикле правильно пропустить лишние элементы, а не их место поставить нужные

Comment: Про break, continue и if() читали?

Comment: Какие именно миноры требуется посчитать - не те ли, в которых только один столбец и одна строка вычеркиваются (дополнительные)?

Comment: да, это были они. Задача уже решена. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Логика цикла, пропускающего элементы

```
инициализация;
while( условие продолжения )
{
    if( надо пропустить итерацию? ) continue;
    // действия итерации
}
```

циклы for() и do-while работает так же. Для многомерных массивов вложенность цикла будет выше.

```
инициализация;
while( условие продолжения по строкам)
{
    if( надо пропустить итерацию? ) continue;
    // действия итерации
    инициализация;
    while( условие продолжения по столбцам )
    {
        if( надо пропустить итерацию? ) continue;
        // действия итерации
    }
}
```

В упрощенном случае, для копирования массива:

```
строка = столбец =  ист_строка = ист_столбец = 0;

while( ист_строка < число_строк_источника )
{
    if(ист_строка в списке пропускаемых ) {
      ист_строка += 1;
      continue;
    } 
    else 
    {
      while( ист_столбец меньше чем число_столбцов_источника )
      {
        if( ист_столбец в списке пропускаемых ) {
            ист_столбец += 1;
            continue;
        else {
           цель[строка][столбец] = источник[ист_строка][ист_столбец]
           ист_столбец += 1;
           столбец += 1;
        }
      }
      ист_строка += 1;
      строка += 1;
    }
}
```

По-моему нигде не ошибся. Тяжесть все это еще в том что проверка , пропускаем ли мы столбец или строку - тоже цикл. В виде функции желательно. "Облегчить" это можно введя статический массив с флагом в элементе, соответствующим пропускному столбцу или строке.

Можно обойтсь более простым и эффективным циклом по строкам и столбцам  целевого минора, но дляэтого надо сначала сформировать "карты" соответсвия  индексов. Пусть макс. размер массива равен 10, тогда надо заранее сформировать массивы со следующими значениями на основе ввода пользователя:

```
   //пропущены столбцы с индексами 2 и 4
   int столбцы[10] = { 0, 1, 3, 5, -1 }; 
   // взяты только строки с индексами 1 и 2
   int строки[10] = { 1, 2, -1 };
```

Тогда цикл выглядит так

```
   // -1 является концом списка индексов.
   int ист_строка, ист_столбец;
   for(int строка = 0; (ист_строка = строки[строка]) != -1; ++строка )
   {
      for(int столбец = 0; (ист_столбец = столбцы[столбец]) != -1; ++столбец )
          цель[строка][столбец] = источник[ист_строка][ист_столбец]
   }
```

PS. В реальности стараются избегать необходимости использовать вложенные циклы с ветвлениями как первый пример т.к. современные процессоры справляются с ними хуже чем с непрерывным копированием, что отражается на организации используемых данных. В данном случае сами условия задачи форсируют использование такого кода.

Comment: допустим я пропустил лишние элементы, но на их место ведь необходимо поставить те что стоят после них, ведь иначе невозможно будет произвести дальнейшие операции.

Comment: @MyLittleMasya хотя упражнение хорошее, в реальности компилятор теряет способность оптимизировать такой цикл, а большинство процессоров начинают "жить" в "параллельных мирах" пытаясь вычислить обе ветки. (в данном случае - 9 веток) Вот поэтому есть стандартные  компоненты  алгоритмов ("стандартные шаблоны stl" является неверным термином), которые являются как бы заметками  компилятору "вот тут мы делаем это, у тебя может быть шаблон машинного кода для такой задачи".

Comment: @MyLittleMasyaнадо иметь два пары индексов  и инкрементировать целевые только когда копирование происходит. Либо делать карты преобразования индексов (второй пример). А еще более правильный способ который используется на практике вместо этих  извращений заключается в том что копирование не происходит до последнего момента. Вместого этого есть "отображение" одной матрицы в минор, Но для этого удобно использовать указатели и классы.

Comment: спасибо. Решил, что проще нарушить идиотские правила и использовать векторы)